# Correct use of R naive_bayes() and predict()

Tags: r, naivebayes

I am trying to run a simple naive bayes model (trying to redo what I have seen the datacamp course).

I am using the R `naivebayes` package.

The training dataset is `where9am` which looks like this:

[image: where9am]

My first problem is the following... when I have several predictions in a dataframe  `thursday9am`...

[image: thursday9am]

... and I use the following code:

```
locmodel <- naive_bayes(location ~ daytype, data = where9am)
my_pred <- predict(locmodel, thursday9am)
```

I get a series of `<NA>` while it works well with the correct prediction if the `thursday9am` dataframe only contains a single observation.

[image: output with multiple rows to predict]

[image: output with a single prediction]

The second problem is the following: when I use the following code to get the associated probabilities...

```
locmodel <- naive_bayes(location ~ daytype, data = where9am, type = c("class", "prob"))
predict(locmodel, thursday9am , type = "prob")
```

... even if I have only one observation in `thursday9am`, I get a series of `<NaN>`.

[image: output with type = "prob"]

I am not sure what I am doing wrong.

Comment: Please [see here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) on how to post an R question that folks can answer. We don't have your data, so we can't recreate the situation. Please also post all code and console output as formatted text, not images.

Comment: I ran exactly the code that you provided and _did not_ get the NAS. I got the expected prediction of `office`. You should check `where9am` and `thursday9am`  to make sure that they contain what you expect.